# How to remove dashed rectangle when doing drag and drop

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I'm following Bea Stollnitz's [blog post](http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/488#.ULTb4qzO0kU) on implementing drag and drop on an data bound ItemsControl. It works very nicely, but I have a question for anyone who's experienced something similar...

When I begin dragging the item, there is a small, dashed rectangle at the bottom of the mouse. I cannot figure out at all how to hide that rectangle. Does anyone know how to get rid of this? I would add a screenshot, but when I do a Print Screen, the rectangle doesn't appear.

I think it has something to do with a focus setting on the `AdornerLayer` that the "DraggedAdorner" is added to.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in the `Style` of the `Visual` that is surrounded by the rectangle:

```
<Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
```

EDIT: The effect that you are seeing is a result of the `DragDropEffects.Move` assignment. You can mitigate this visual by simply changing the following line (Line #168 in the sample):

```
DragDropEffects effects = DragDrop.DoDragDrop((DependencyObject)sender, data, DragDropEffects.Move);
```

To this:

```
DragDropEffects effects = DragDrop.DoDragDrop((DependencyObject)sender, data, DragDropEffects.None);
```

Thus setting the DragDropEffect to DragDropEffects.None

NOTE: In the sample, it evaluates the `DragDropEffects` value in the process of performing the drag & drop, so you would need to work around this (Probably a simple `AttachedProperty`, or even casting the `Sender` as a `FrameworkElement` and using the `Tag` property), but this should resolve the ***visual*** issue.

I hope this helps, and if I can help you further feel free to let me know. Good luck!

Comment: Assuming I added this to the correct location, it didn't work. In the class that inherits from `Adorner`, I set the `FocusVisualStyle` to NULL on both the adorner layer and the adorner itself and neither worked.

Comment: Hmmm. It would be helpful to see an image, but I envision it similar to the focus visual style that most FrameworkElements have by default. Maybe it's not in the AdornerLayer at all? What type of visual are you seeing this behavior on?

Comment: I have a DataTemplate (with a TextBlock inside), which is assigned to the ContentTemplate of a ContentPresenter inside Adorner.

Comment: Have you used Snoop to figure out which element is responsible for the outline?

Comment: I have not...I'll give that a try.

Comment: I'm new to Snoop, but it seems like I can't "snoop" the actual object being dragged...that is, in the process of dragging, I can't examine the state.

Comment: I guess I've never tried that either. Do you have some sample code that duplicates the issue? If you want to email me something I can test against, I will happily try to help. There just simply is not enough information available to go beyond speculation and educated guesses here. :)

Comment: You can replicate the issue using the blog post sample I am using: http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/488#.ULTb4qzO0kU  

In the sample, there is an image being dragged, but in the top left of the image is the rectangle I'm talking about. Thanks for looking into this, I appreciate it.

Comment: I edited the answer above to include what I believe is the solution to your issue. I hope this is helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks...yeah, I actually just came to the same conclusion that it was the DragDropEffects. I still have some work to do I think to get what I'm looking for, but you've answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

The dashed rectangle is actually part of the default cursor used when performing a drag and drop "Move" operation.

This is the default "Move" cursor:
[image: move cursor]

And this is the default "Copy" cursor (if you hold CTRL while dragging):
[image: copy cursor]

You can get more control over what mouse cursor is shown by overriding `UIElement.OnGiveFeedback`, or subscribing to the `UIElement.GiveFeedback` [Routed Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/routed-events-overview).

When handling the event and changing the cursor, make sure to set `e.Handled = true;` to prevent the cursor from flickering.

For example, use this override on the element initiating the Drag operation (see [this walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-enabling-drag-and-drop-on-a-user-control) for more info):

```
protected override void OnGiveFeedback(GiveFeedbackEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Effects.HasFlag(DragDropEffects.Copy))
    {
        Mouse.SetCursor(Cursors.Cross);
    }
    else if (e.Effects.HasFlag(DragDropEffects.Move))
    {
        Mouse.SetCursor(Cursors.Pen);
    }
    else
    {
        Mouse.SetCursor(Cursors.No);
    }

    e.Handled = true;
}
```